# Fetch failed in OE BitBake

Tags: git, github, bitbake, openembedded

BitBake is internally using the following git command to fetch:

```
$ git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git://github.com/google/leveldb.git

Error Log:
    $<50>ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/home/rajeshgopu/github.com.google.leveldb.git'...
fatal: Project not found: github.com/google/leveldb
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If I manually try the same command it fails. I edited it below then it works:

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git@github.com:google/leveldb.git
```

How can I configure this in `.gitconfig` instead of manually changing it in all projects?

I tried the following but got the same error:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = git://github.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked after adding the below in ~/.gitconfig

```
[url "https://github.com"]
         insteadOf = git://github.com
```